# Coldfusion <cfsavecontent> variable displays correctly on page but does not save correctly to the DB

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have AJAX writing a result to `<span id="response"></span>`, which displays as expected.  But, I need to convert to a CF variable so I can write the content to the database.  Using
`<cfsavecontent variable="JSONResponse"><span id="response"></span></cfsavecontent>` 
allows me to display the new **JSONResponse** variable on the page correctly, but when I take the same varible and write it to the database, it writes the `<span id="response"></span>` tag into the table - not the actual content.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: What is the value of the JSONResponse variable?  Based on what you said in your question, `<cfsavecontent variable="JSONResponse"><span id="response"></span></cfsavecontent>`,  my expected value is, `<span id="response"></span>`.

Comment: Do you want to write only the JSOn response and not the HTML, can you clarify your question, What exactly you are trying to do here

Comment: Comment from GSR - Do you want to write only the JSOn response and not the HTML, can you clarify your question, What exactly you are trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks - the value being passed to the DIV and displayed on the page is a JSON string.  I want to take that string and write it to the database.  I can't find a way of converting the AJAX variable into a CF variable any other way.  I was hoping that this would work, as it is displaying the json string on the page correctly if I simply do a cfoutput around the cfsavecontent created #JSONResponse# variable.

Comment: Thanks - the value being passed to the DIV and displayed on the page is a JSON string. I want to take that string and write it to the database. I can't find a way of converting the AJAX variable into a CF variable any other way. I was hoping that this would work, as it is displaying the json string on the page correctly if I simply do a cfoutput around the cfsavecontent created #JSONResponse# variable. – Jeremy Kwee just now

Comment: Does your ajax call go to a ColdFusion page?

Comment: Yes, the AJAX is being called and the result is displayed in a DIV on a .cfm page.

Comment: Can you show some kind of dummy fiddle which can give exact idea as to how it should loo like and how it is now. @JeremyKwee

Comment: @DanBracuk Thanks, Even you have already Specified the Option of using `CHAR`, but Thanks for letting me add my Answer which is exactly the same what you specified, `CHAR` will solve his problem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @GSR & @Dan - I managed to work out a solution by forwarding on to a CFM page that writes to the DB, via another nested ajax post, based upon the response:

```
var postData = {username: "user@company.com",   password: "Ruu3992032!883jj22uje"};

        var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "https://api.company.com/v1/authenticate",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify( postData ) 
        })

        // When the response comes back, forward on to another cfm page with insert statement.
        ajaxResponse.then(
            function( apiResponse ){

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "WriteToDB.cfm",
            data: jQuery.param({ payload: JSON.stringify( apiResponse ) }) ,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        })
            }
        );
```

Comment: Is it my imagination or are you stringifying the original string twice?